# Where is the TFS 2010 "main" build log?

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm trying to track down some problems with unit tests in a test TFS 2010 build.  The overall log file reports an error being returned from MSTest, but the only log files I can find, the log files for the individual projects being compiled, indicate no problems.  Where can I locate the "main" log file that is used to generate the build report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the build log is just kept in the database and is not written out to disk.

Answer (score 1):

After the build has run, you can view the build from the build menu (found in the project folder of the Team Explorer window)

From there, the default view is the "View Summary" in near the top-left corner of the window is a "View Log" option. From there, you can see more details as to what happened with the build.

Comment: Thanks McKay.  I've seen this before, but it doesn't contain all the information about a build.  Anything for a "purely" 2010 build not specifically related to building is not in this log.  For example, any logs relating to running code analysis are not present.

Comment: I am missing the detailed log as well. When errors occur that are not inside a solution build it's very hard to tell where they originate.