# Where to begin troubleshooting whether a custom assembly is being referenced or not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am pretty new to TFS and I was trying to setup a versioning step as part of my build process. I am using a third party open source tool called [TFS Versioning](http://tfsversioning.codeplex.com/).

As part of the installation I have:

1. Checked in the "TFS Versioning" DLL
2. Checked in the BuildProcessTemplate
3. Modified the "Version control path to custom assemblies:" property of my Build Controller to be the directory containing my DLL
4. Reset the Build Controller
5. Modified one of my existing builds to use the new BuildProcessTemplate

After that, I kicked off a build and noticed that the "versioning" step did not execute. I suspect that the tool works correctly, but perhaps I did not install it correctly. I even modified the code so that it would throw an exception on the following procedure:

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
```

But my build ran correctly, and it seemed to have just ignored the versioning step of my build process. Is there anyway to confirm that my DLL is being loaded? Where should I start looking to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the ["Version Control path for Custom Assemblies" on the build controller?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330987.aspx)

Comment: Yup.. Mentioned that in step 3

Comment: And - just to verify - you have added the activity to the build template?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so I just used the build template that was provided by the TFS Versioning folks. I am not really sure what I am supposed to see in the build template, but I do see attributes in the Activity element referencing the dll.. is there something specific I should be looking for?

Comment: Did you turn on the verbosity logging? it tells you exactly what step is executed and what values the variables have. You can enable the verbosity logging with one of the properties in the build definition

Comment: I hate to ask this.. but I've been looking around and couldn't find it... Where are the logs stored? I saw some logs (one for each solution) on my build machine.. Are those the logs you are referring to? I also tried to follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922120/where-is-the-tfs-2010-main-build-log ..... But, I don't see the View Log option in VS2010

Comment: The log is in the drop folder and in the 'working directory' of the build machine.